# A function who's image is $\mathbb{R}$ on every interval

Tags: calculus

I was wondering if there exists a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the property that for every $a<b$, $Image(f|_{(a, b)})=\mathbb{R}$.
I tried to show that there isn't but falied. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For another counterexample unfortunately I cannot recall the reference, I have seen this a while back.

Let $ \mathbb{R} /\ \mathbb{Q}$ so $[x] = [y]$ if and only if $x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$.

because $\mathbb{R} /\ \mathbb{Q}$ has the same cardinatlity as $\mathbb{R}$ we get a surjection

$h:\mathbb{R} /\ \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Now and define $f (x) = h([x])$. The important algebraic property of $\mathbb{R} /\ \mathbb{Q}$ is that in any interval $(a,b)$ there is a full set of representatives, since for any $x$ we can find $r$ a rational number such that 
$x-r\in (a,b)$.

And hence $f( (a,b)) = \mathbb{R}$. for any interval.

Comment: Thanks! Very nice, and easy to understand

Answer (score 9):

Conway's base 13 function does exactly what you want: it maps every non-empty open interval to the whole of $\mathbb R$. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) for details.

Note that this function is discontinuous everywhere. If you require a continuous $f$, then it can't be done.

Comment: How about somewhere continuous?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 if it was at a point continuous then in a neighborhood of that point all the values would be near the value there

Comment: Thank you, buy wow, I didn't manage to follow